# Concat and append in pandas datafarme

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have three data frame with the same dimension, and I need to concatenate them as a single data frame.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'AD': ['CTA15', 'CTA15', 'AC007', 'AC007', 'AC007'], 
'FC': [0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 2.6, 2.9], 
'EX':['12', '13', '14', '15', '16'], 
't' : [2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
 'P' :[3,7,8,9,1]})
df2 = df1.copy()
df3 = df1.copy()
df = df1.append([df2, df3])
```

I tried append and concate, both returns me with a data frame without the first column.
This is what I tried,

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]) and df1.append([df2,df3])
```

Concat works if I set the first column of all data frames as index using `df1.set_index('col1')` and so for df2 and df3. Then with pd.concat it works, not otherwise. Would be great if there is a direct solution
Thank you

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=0)` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it didn't help. I could concat when I set the first column as index for all datafarmes and then do pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]), not otherwise

Comment: Is 1st column name same ?

Comment: Yes its the same name

Comment: Check whether misspell or have space

Comment: Just post your data, it'll be faster and easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], ignore_index=True)

       AD  EX   FC  P  t
0   CTA15  12  0.5  3  2
1   CTA15  13  0.7  7  2
2   AC007  14  0.7  8  3
3   AC007  15  2.6  9  3
4   AC007  16  2.9  1  3
5   CTA15  12  0.5  3  2
6   CTA15  13  0.7  7  2
7   AC007  14  0.7  8  3
8   AC007  15  2.6  9  3
9   AC007  16  2.9  1  3
10  CTA15  12  0.5  3  2
11  CTA15  13  0.7  7  2
12  AC007  14  0.7  8  3
13  AC007  15  2.6  9  3
14  AC007  16  2.9  1  3
```